# Inconsistency and abrupt behaviour of Spark filter, current timestamp and HBase custom sink in Spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I've a HBase table which look like following in a static Dataframe as HBaseStaticRecorddf

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|rowkey|Name|Number|message|lastTS|
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|266915488007398|somename|8759620897|Hi|1539931239            |
|266915488007399|somename|8759620898|Welcome|1540314926       |
|266915488007400|somename|8759620899|Hello|1540315092         |
|266915488007401|somename|8759620900|Namaskar|1537148280      |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I've a file stream source from which I'll get streaming rowkey. Now this timestamp(lastTS) for streaming rowkey's has to be checked whether they're older than one day or not. For this I've the following code where joinedDF is a streaming DataFrame, which is formed by joining another streaming DataFrame and HBase static dataframe as follows.

```scala
val HBaseStreamDF = HBaseStaticRecorddf.join(anotherStreamDF,"rowkey")

val newdf = HBaseStreamDF.filter(HBaseStreamDF.col("lastTS").cast("Long") < ((System.currentTimeMillis - 86400*1000)/1000))//records older than one day are eligible to get updated
```

Once the filter is done I want to save this record to the HBase like below.

```scala
   newDF.writeStream
  .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    println("inside foreach")

    val tableName: String = "dummy"
    val hbaseConfResources: Seq[String] = Seq("hbase-site.xml")
    private var hTable: Table = _
    private var connection: Connection = _


    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      connection = createConnection()
      hTable = getHTable(connection)
      true
    }

    def createConnection(): Connection = {
      val hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create()
      hbaseConfResources.foreach(hbaseConfig.addResource)
      ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConfig)

    }

    def getHTable(connection: Connection): Table = {
      connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName))
    }

    override def process(record: Row): Unit = {
      var put = saveToHBase(record)
      hTable.put(put)
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
      hTable.close()
      connection.close()
    }

    def saveToHBase(record: Row): Put = {
    val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(record.getString(0)))
    println("Now updating HBase for " + record.getString(0))


      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("messageInfo"),
        Bytes.toBytes("ts"),
        Bytes.toBytes((System.currentTimeMillis/1000).toString)) //saving as second

      p
    }

  }
  ).outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
  .start().awaitTermination()
```

Now when any record is coming HBase is getting updated for the first time only. If the same record comes afterwards, it's just getting neglected and not working. However if some unique record comes which has not been processed by the Spark application, then it works. So any duplicated record is not getting processed for the second time.

Now here's some interesting thing.

1. If I remove the 86400 sec subtraction from (System.currentTimeMillis - 86400*1000)/1000) then everything is getting processed even if there's redundancy among the incoming records. But it's not intended and useful as it doesn't filter 1 day older records.
2. If I do the comparison in the filter condition in milliseconds without dividing by 1000(this requires HBase data also in millisecond) and save the record as second in the put object then again everything is processed. But If I change the format to seconds in the put object then it doesn't work.

I tried testing individually the filter and HBase put and they both works fine. But together they mess up if System.currentTimeMillis in filter has some arithmetic operations such as /1000 or -864000. If I remove the HBase sink part and use

```scala
newDF.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

then again the filter logic works. And If I remove the filter then HBase sink works fine. But together, the custom sink for the HBase only works for the first time for the unique records. I tried several other filter logic like below but issue remains the same.

```scala
val newDF = newDF1.filter(col("lastTS").lt(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"))))
```

or

```scala
val newDF = newDF1.filter(col("lastTS").cast("Long") < LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")))
```

How do I make the filter work and save the filtered records to the HBase with updated timestamp? I took reference of several other posts. But the result is same.